# How to change popularity_score?

Tags: typesense

So Typesense sorts the results by popularity_score. How can I change it? I would like to bump some popularity_scores based on some counters like views, likes, shares. Maybe I should ignore popularity_score that Typesense automatically creates and create my own field which is like a small algorithm based on these counts and sort by that field instead of the popularity_score?

Learn about popularity_score parameters, there isn’t enough documentation on this topic

Answer (score 0):

The popularity_score field in the docs is just an example. Typesense does not auto-calculate it.

Instead you would calculate the score on your side using any criteria and set a field to use for sorting in addition to the text relevance score (which is what Typesense calculates).

Comment: That makes sense! I had no idea it was acting just as an example. So I can simply create my own popularity_score. Anyways, let’s say my app has events and when the user is searching for events I would like to have the most popular events first (which is easy) but also I would like to give some weight for the events closer to the user? Not necessarily only events like 5km away, just more weight, events very far away could show up in the search anyways. How can I do that given that I have the event coordinates stored in a field?